# What is the reason, not to change the props after submitting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm new to react and I'm developing a very simple app with MySQL database. Here I submit reviews to the DB and get the data back from the DB to the UI. After hitting on the submit button, It doesn't display an updated movie and review list on the UI. Also, props don't change. Please help me to understand the wrong I did here. Also, any improvements in the code are welcome.

[Strcture of the App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpMqb.png)

App.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { addReview } from './actions/actionReview'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import ReviewList from './components/reviewListComponent'
import Axios from 'axios'

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    review: {
      movie_name: '',
      movie_review: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/get').then(
      (response) => {
        this.setState({ ReviewList: response.data })
      }
    )
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    this.props.addReview(this.state)
  }

  render() {
    const { filmReviews } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Movie Reviews</h1>
        <div className="form">
          <label>Movie Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="film" onChange={this.handleChange} />

          <label>Review</label>
          <input type="text" id="review" onChange={this.handleChange} />

          <button
            onClick={this.handleSubmit}
          >Submit
        </button>
          <h1>Review List</h1>
          <div className='Project-list-section'>
            {this.state.ReviewList && this.state.ReviewList.map(review => {
              return (
                <ReviewList filmReview={review} key={review.id} />
              )
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    filmReviews: state.ReviewList
  }
}

const matchDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addReview: (review) => dispatch(addReview(review))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(App);
```

allReviewReducer.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios'

const initState = {}

function allReviewReducer(state = initState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_REVIEW':
            console.log('Review received', action.addReview)
            fetchReview(action.addReview)
        case 'DISPLAY_ALL_REVIEWS':
            console.log('please display all reviews')
        default:
            return state;
    }
    return state

}


function fetchReview(review) {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/insert",
        {
            movieName: review.film,
            movieReview: review.review
        }).then(() => {
            alert('Successful Insert');
        })
}

export default allReviewReducer
```

rootReducer.js

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import allReviewReducer from './allReviewsReducer'
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    allReview : allReviewReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

reviewListComponent.js

```js
import React from 'react'

const ReviewList = (filmReviews) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>{filmReviews.filmReview.movie_name} || {filmReviews.filmReview.movie_review}</h3>
        </div>

    )
}

export default ReviewList
```

actionReview.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react';

export const addReview = (review) => {

    return (dispatch, getState) => {

        dispatch({
            type: 'ADD_REVIEW',
            addReview: review
        })

    }
}

export default addReview
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do your reviews come from in this snippet?

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react';

export const addReview = (review) => {

    return (dispatch, getState) => {

        dispatch({
            type: 'ADD_REVIEW',
            addReview: review
        })

    }
}

export default addReview
```

Where they need to come from is of course your redux store. That doesn't seem to be the case here. You can get your data easily from your store by using `useSelector` provided by redux, for more on that [read here](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks).

Also, try reading up on `redux-thunk` and how to dispatch asynchronous actions to your redux store. It's an [easy middleware](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) that help you do that.

Next, check your redux store with development tools in your browser so you can see at all time which state it is in. The [redux development tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=de) will let you see when an action was dispatched and how it affected the state of your store. This makes it much easier to see if your store has the correct state.